# AWK keep header of input file in output

Tags: bash, awk

i have an input file that looks like this:

```
datetime,num1,num2
10-01-2015 00:00,1,2
10-01-2015 00:00,4,5
```

my awk code looks like this:

```
awk -F"," '{thisid=substr($1,1,10);if(lastid!=thisid)
{print lastid"|"cnt1"|"cnt2;cnt1=0;cnt2=0;lastid=thisid;}
if($2>=40){cnt1+=1;}if($3>=40){cnt2+=1;}
lastid=thisid;}' input > output
```

i want my output to have the header still:

```
datetime,num1,num2
10-01-2015,0,0
10-01-2015,0,0
```

currently output of header just look like this:

```
datetime|1|1
```

i dont want to manually print the header.

Comment: Do you find it improves readability to not use any white space in your scripts?

Answer (score 4):

Before the opening brace ({), add:

```
NR == 1 {print; next}
```