# awk keep header when using IGNORECASE

Tags: bash, awk, ignore-case

I have a csv file I want to search for a string in a specific column `columnB` (column 5 in my dataset) (case ignored), and apply a filter on another`columnC`(column 10 in my dataset). Then save selected columns to a file.

sample of the dataset

```
columnA     columnB    columnC  columnD
abc          Apple      100     today
nbd          apple      50      tomorrow
ccc          apple      101     today
```

desired output

```
columnB    columnC
Apple      100
apple      101
```

the problem when I use `awk` I can select `columnB`, but I can't output the header.

```
 awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} {if($5 == "Apple") print $0 }' Data.csv> testPipe.txt
```

I have tried using `NR==1` but for some reason it doesn't work with `IGNORECASE`.

### I also tried the methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260548/filter-file-with-awk-and-keep-header-in-output) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33027702/awk-keep-header-of-input-file-in-output).

I tried to use `grip`, I can output the header but I can't specify `columnB` for the string matching.And the search will be applied to all columns.

```
cat Data.csv |{ head -1; grep -I "Apple";} | awk -F',' '{ if ($10 >100 ) { print } }'>testPipe.txt
```

Is there a way to combine both methods and get the desired output?
Thanks

Comment: Wrt *I have tried using NR==1 but for some reason it doesn't work with IGNORECASE.*, did you try `NR==1{print;next}`? It works fine here

Comment: where do you suggest I add this line? in the if condition? `awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} {if($5 == "Apple") NR==1{print;next}}' Data.csv> testPipe.txt`

Comment: It's a condition-action pair, put it after BEGIN rule. Like `awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} NR==1{print;next} $5 == "Apple"' Data.csv> testPipe.txt`

Comment: `awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} NR==1{print;next} 5 == "Apple" && $10>100' FData.csv> testPipeNew.csv` it returns the headers only. with empty columns

Comment: Isn't it normal? Since 5 is never equal to "Apple"???? You're missing a `$` there

Comment: sorry, my bad. 
`awk 'BEGIN {IGNORECASE = 1} NR==1{print;next} $5 == "Apple" && $10>100' FData.csv> testPipeNew.csv` I fixed it and ran the code again. I see output with header, but a lot of the rows don't match the conditions. (rows without 'Apple' in the string, and rows less than 100)

Comment: Can't reproduce here. Maybe you should improve your example input to truly represent your actual data?

Comment: I added few more conditions and it worked. Thank you

Comment: `IGNORECASE` is GNU awk only. What does `awk --version` output? Your input contains 3 rows with `apple` in the target field but your expected output only contains 2 of those rows. Why?

Comment: because columns C is <100

Answer (score 2):

Use the function `tolower()`:

```
awk 'NR==1{print; next} tolower($5) == "apple"' file
```

Explanation:

```
# Print the headers
NR==1 {
    print
    next
}

# Print the current line if $5 matches the condition
# Note that if there is no action specified, awk will
# use print $0 by default
tolower($5)
```

If you want to write further actions if the condition is true, put them into a block

```
tolower($5) {
    ...
}
```

In opposite to `IGNORECASE` which works only with GNU awk, the `tolower()` will work with any version of `awk` because it is defined by POSIX.

Comment: Thanks, do you know it converts the final outcome?

Comment: you may just try it

Comment: it works for the matching part, and it does not change the case. Is it possible to add another condition, when I do it doesn't remove nulls. I might be doing something wrong here. `awk 'NR==1{print;next} tolower($5)=="apple" && $5 !="NULL"' FData.csv>match.csv`

Comment: @leena It is very confusing when you drop more requirements to comments of various answers. Please, don't do that. Rather update the original question with updated data sample with the related expected output or ask a new question.

Comment: I mentioned in my post that I would like to print selected columns once I get the required output. –

Comment: What's the problem with printing them?

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** apparently my answer isn't as good as I thought, see the comment from Ed Morton below. I'll keep it anyway, as a "How not to do it".

**Original (bad) answer:**

add the following to your BEGIN clause, either before or after setting IGNORECASE:

```
getline;
print;
```

explanation: the BEGIN clause is executed once before everything else, so you can process lines there, too, but you have to read them in manually.

full example:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        getline;
        print;
        IGNORECASE = 1;
    }

    $2 == "apple" && $3 <= 100 {
        print $1;
    }
'
```

Comment: like this? `awk 'BEGIN getline; print; {IGNORECASE = 1} {if($5 == "Apple") print $0 }' FData.csv>2222.csv` sorry I am a beginner in Bash. Looking forward for your clarification. Thanks

Comment: thank you, it works perfectly. I just needed to change the 1 to 0.  is their a way to select specific columns in the print statement? such as `{print $4,$5,$10}` and do I need to modify the code if I want to save the result in a text file? thank you

Comment: I ran the code again. Some of the rows don't match the conditions :( any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You don't need/want to use getline for this. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks for enlightening me, I added a comment